# Golang decode array of strings

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to decode an array of strings in golang and cannot unmarshall this json in golang

```
"{\"keys\":[\"CovePDF:metadata:deadlineDate:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:endedOnDate:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:moderators:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:reviewers:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:title:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:initiator:asfsdbdjh\",\"CovePDF:metadata:startOnDate:asfsdbdjh\"]}"
```

my struct looks like this:

```
type Keys struct {
     keys []string `json:"keys"`
}
```

and than trying to do

```
    keys := args[0] 
    ks := Keys{}
    err0 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(keys), &ks)
```

I got an error in the logs of:

> error: unexpected end of JSON input
>   error: Unmarshal unexpected end of JSON input
>   error: unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON package can only process exported struct fields (e.g. start with a capital letter). That's why you use the JSON tag so you can change the tag name/case to use.

Otherwise, this works as you would expect. See example:

https://play.golang.org/p/pRVKNrekWe